# MYsql INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with IF

Tags: mysql

I have sy_version table which have 2 primary key mod_id and sub_mod

```
CREATE TABLE `sy_version` (
`mod_id` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
`sub_mod` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`version` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`remark` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`update_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`download_link` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`file` BLOB NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`mod_id`, `sub_mod`)
)COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

And my data is

```
CS;sbm_sl.exe;2015.11.01;IBS Sales App;2015-11-10 11:34:13;\N;0x73002E00000000
```

I want to update my data using insert into on duplicate key, for the first it working fine. But Everytime I executed i get my file column become NULL, result that i want is : file become NULL when version where i want to set is bigger the present(original) version. And the command is like below

```
INSERT INTO sbm_sys.sy_version (mod_id,sub_mod,`version`,remark,update_date,file) 
values ('CS','sbm_sl.exe','2015.11.07.1','IBS Sales App','2015-11-10 11:34:13', NULL) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `version`='2015.11.07.1', remark='IBS Sales App', 
update_date='2015-11-10 11:34:13', file=if(VALUES(version)>version,null,file) ;
```

It doesn't work fine, file column is not become NULL but the other columns is updated, so i try change the part become, and it work as i hoped

```
file=if(VALUES(version)>version,null,file) ==> file=if(VALUES(version)>'2015.11.01',null,file) ;
```

The question is how I can't get "2015.01.01" from original version value?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Please, do NOT cross-post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121920/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-with-if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with MySQL. It's possible that `VALUES(version)>version` is using the *updated* `version` and not its original value. This differs from standard SQL and is [mentioned here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html).

Change the order of your assignments so that the test comes first.